# Close Client after the server respond

Tags: c#, client-server

The only thing i want to change is to close the client connection after the client send message to the server and received respond from the server.
what i need to change in the client code ?

Server

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

// State object for reading client data asynchronously
public class StateObject
{
// Client  socket.
public Socket workSocket = null;
// Size of receive buffer.
public const int BufferSize = 1024;
// Receive buffer.
public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
// Received data string.
public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
}

public class AsynchronousSocketListener
{
// Thread signal.
public static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

public AsynchronousSocketListener()
{
}

public static void StartListening()
{
    // Data buffer for incoming data.
    byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];

    // Establish the local endpoint for the socket.
    // The DNS name of the computer
    // running the listener is "host.contoso.com".
    //IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
    //IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
    IPAddress ipAddress = System.Net.IPAddress.Loopback;
    IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 3000);

    // Create a TCP/IP socket.
    Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
        SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

    // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen for incoming connections.
    try
    {
        listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
        listener.Listen(100);

        while (true)
        {
            // Set the event to nonsignaled state.
            allDone.Reset();

            // Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections.
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
            listener.BeginAccept(
                new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),
                listener);

            // Wait until a connection is made before continuing.
            allDone.WaitOne();
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\nPress ENTER to continue...");
    Console.Read();

}

public static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    // Signal the main thread to continue.
    allDone.Set();

    // Get the socket that handles the client request.
    Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
    Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

    // Create the state object.
    StateObject state = new StateObject();
    state.workSocket = handler;
    handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
        new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
}

public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    String content = String.Empty;

    // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket
    // from the asynchronous state object.
    StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
    Socket handler = state.workSocket;

    // Read data from the client socket. 
    int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

    if (bytesRead > 0)
    {
        // There  might be more data, so store the data received so far.
        state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
            state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));

        // Check for end-of-file tag. If it is not there, read 
        // more data.
        content = state.sb.ToString();
        if (content.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1)
        {
            // All the data has been read from the 
            // client. Display it on the console.
            Console.WriteLine("Read {0} bytes from socket. \n Data : {1}",
                content.Length, content);
            // Echo the data back to the client.
            Send(handler, content);
        }
        else
        {
            // Not all data received. Get more.
            handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
        }
    }
}

private static void Send(Socket handler, String data)
{
    // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.
    byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

    // Begin sending the data to the remote device.
    handler.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
        new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);
}

private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
        Socket handler = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

        // Complete sending the data to the remote device.
        int bytesSent = handler.EndSend(ar);
        Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to client.", bytesSent);

        handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        handler.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}


public static int Main(String[] args)
{
    StartListening();
    return 0;
}
}
```

Client:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

public class StateObject
{
    // Client socket.
    public Socket workSocket = null;
    // Size of receive buffer.
    public const int BufferSize = 256;
    // Receive buffer.
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
    // Received data string.
    public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
}

public class Program
{
    public static ManualResetEvent connectDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    public static ManualResetEvent sendDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    public static ManualResetEvent receiveDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    public static void Connect(EndPoint remoteEP, Socket client)
    {
        client.BeginConnect(remoteEP,
            new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);

        connectDone.WaitOne();
    }
    private static void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
            Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete the connection.
            client.EndConnect(ar);

            Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}",
                client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

            // Signal that the connection has been made.
            connectDone.Set();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
    private static void Send(Socket client, String data)
    {
        // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.
        byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

        // Begin sending the data to the remote device.
        client.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, SocketFlags.None,
            new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), client);
    }
    private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
            Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete sending the data to the remote device.
            int bytesSent = client.EndSend(ar);
            Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to server.", bytesSent);

            // Signal that all bytes have been sent.
            sendDone.Set();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
    private static void Receive(Socket client)
    {
        try
        {
            // Create the state object.
            StateObject state = new StateObject();
            state.workSocket = client;

            // Begin receiving the data from the remote device.
            client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
    private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the state object and the client socket 
            // from the asynchronous state object.
            StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket client = state.workSocket;
            // Read data from the remote device.
            int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);
            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                // There might be more data, so store the data received so far.
                state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));
                //  Get the rest of the data.
                client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                    new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
            }
            else
            {
                // All the data has arrived; put it in response.
                if (state.sb.Length > 1)
                {
                    string response = state.sb.ToString();
                    Console.WriteLine(response);
                }
                // Signal that all bytes have been received.
                receiveDone.Set();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IPAddress ipAddress = System.Net.IPAddress.Loopback;
        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 3000);
        Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,SocketType.Stream,ProtocolType.Tcp);
        Connect(localEndPoint, sock);
        string packet;
        while (true)
        {
            packet = Console.ReadLine();
            packet += "<EOF>";
            Send(sock, packet);
            Receive(sock);
            connectDone.WaitOne();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `while` loop in `Main` will run indefinitely.

```
    while (true)
    {
        packet = Console.ReadLine();
        packet += "<EOF>";
        Send(sock, packet);
        Receive(sock);
        connectDone.WaitOne();
    }
```

either remove it entirely (so that it runs only once) or add in a condition to exit the `while` loop.

as Diego pointed out the in the comments, you should close the socket after you are done, by

```
sock.Close();
```

Comment: Well, the idea is close the application first, so the Socket will close by the GC? if it is, bad idea. Anyway that has not to do with your spot in the loop of course.

Comment: @DiegoCNascimento Thanks for pointing that out, updated the answer to include it.

Comment: After i removed the while and socket.Close() the server crashed in private static void Send method because the connection is lost (SocketException) so i out this server relevant code inside try - catch(SocketException) - is it ok to do so ?