# Change my client to enable the program to return the respond from the server

Tags: c#, client-server

Client

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

public class StateObject
{
    // Client socket.
    public Socket workSocket = null;
    // Size of receive buffer.
    public const int BufferSize = 256;
    // Receive buffer.
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
    // Received data string.
    public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
}

public class Program
{
    public static ManualResetEvent connectDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    public static ManualResetEvent sendDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    public static ManualResetEvent receiveDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    public static void Connect(EndPoint remoteEP, Socket client)
    {
        client.BeginConnect(remoteEP,
            new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);

        connectDone.WaitOne();
    }
    private static void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
            Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete the connection.
            client.EndConnect(ar);

            Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}",
                client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

            // Signal that the connection has been made.
            connectDone.Set();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
    private static void Send(Socket client, String data)
    {
        // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.
        byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

        // Begin sending the data to the remote device.
        client.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, SocketFlags.None,
            new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), client);
    }
    private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
            Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete sending the data to the remote device.
            int bytesSent = client.EndSend(ar);
            Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to server.", bytesSent);

            // Signal that all bytes have been sent.
            sendDone.Set();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
    private static void Receive(Socket client)
    {
        try
        {
            // Create the state object.
            StateObject state = new StateObject();
            state.workSocket = client;

            // Begin receiving the data from the remote device.
            client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
    private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the state object and the client socket 
            // from the asynchronous state object.
            StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket client = state.workSocket;
            // Read data from the remote device.
            int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);
            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                // There might be more data, so store the data received so far.
                state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));
                //  Get the rest of the data.
                client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                    new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
            }
            else
            {
                // All the data has arrived; put it in response.
                if (state.sb.Length > 1)
                {
                    string response = state.sb.ToString();
                    Console.WriteLine(response);
                }
                // Signal that all bytes have been received.
                receiveDone.Set();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //IPAddress ipAddress = System.Net.IPAddress.Loopback;
        IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.100");
        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 1515);
        Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        Connect(localEndPoint, sock);
        string packet;
        //while (true)
        //{
            packet = Console.ReadLine();
            packet += "<EOF>";
            Send(sock, packet);
            Receive(sock);
            connectDone.WaitOne();
        //}
    }
}
```

This is my client and this client i am going to execute via another program via its exe file and all i want to change is that this mail to return a string from the server respond and close after the server respond.
what i need to change in this code ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Close Client after the server respond](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18769589/close-client-after-the-server-respond) (Near equal question, what's that, a homework?)

Comment: You asked a nearly identical question on the cited link. The close connection is solved in the other question does not? What you mean by _execute via another program via its exe file_ is _launch this program by other process_. But yes I can understood that, but what about _this mail to return a string from the server respond_. Mail? Could you elaborate better?

Comment: My server return string and from the client side i want to parse this string to int (the server will return number), now about the exe file i mean that the if i want to run the exe via command line from another program i will open process and run this exe file, how my question is how to catch the server respond ?

Comment: Why this example isn't a good client - server ? do you have maybe an batter example ? i am looking for server that can received several connection and from each connection receive string and return string and after that i want the client will close the connection

Comment: There's so much to point. But perhaps the most important I already said, you don't have a good application layer protocol. Your end of connection is the `<EOF>` sequence of chars. What if the data you want to send has that? crash.

Comment: Do you have an batter application, something simple ?

Comment: I found this article: http://codeabout.wordpress.com/2011/03/06/building-a-simple-server-client-application-using-c/ and it seems that is very simple, send to the server simple string and received back respond, in my case i am sending back to the client process id and when the client wants to close this process (who running on the server machine) he send to the server back this process id and the server machine close this process, you think it should work ?

Comment: As the title says its just a start point to building a client-server application direct on TCP/IP. I don't know what is your intentions with the server, if its for production release, or like you said now a simple, simple thing. It should work, but it has its problems, security, performance, etc. Anyway I said about Java classes thinking you are using Java, sorry my mistake.

Comment: This one i enough for my purpose but the only question i have is: the client side running from another program that send argument with the client.exe to the server, how can i catch the server respond ?